# Unable to call index.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jdeveloper

I'm working on a java web application stuffed with JSPs & servlets through jDeveloper IDE.
The integrated server I'm using is Weblogic.

In middle of my application, if I remove the path till the context root, the java code written on my index.jsp isn't getting executed.

Also index page entry is provided in web.xml

For Ex. :

my app url is `http://localhost:7101/DAMS/index.jsp`
In middle somewhere I'm on the url : `http://localhost:7101/DAMS/pages/activate.jsp`
Here if I remove "/pages/activate.jsp" from my URL, the SOP written on my index.jsp isn't printed.  Any clues ?

What I wish to do is if someone hits the index page, I wish to invalidate session by calling `session.invalidate();` on index.jsp.

web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>OnSaveMedicaidOption</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.restat.db.OnSaveMedicaidOption</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>OnSaveMedicaidOption</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/OnSaveMedicaidOption</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>PostData</display-name>
    <servlet-name>PostData</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.restat.db.PostData</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PostData</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/postData</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

SOP** = System.out.println();

Thanks

Comment: Where have you placed your index.jsp? Is it directly under web root or under pages directory?

Comment: Post your url-mappings for your servlets.

Comment: @dkaustubh directly under web root...

Comment: @HarsH1610 There doesn't seem to be anything mapped to handle `DAMS/pages/activate.jsp`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Correct, this jsp '/pages/activate.jsp' is called from an href tag, and I hope this doesn't require mapping. Though, my question is regarding the next part, if URL is manipulated and kept only till the context-root code on index page (index.jsp) should be executed. Does this need mapping of activate.jsp in web.xml ?

Comment: @HarsH1610 For `/pages/activate.jsp` It depends where it is in your project directory structure.

Comment: something specific ? I'm getting confused... sorry

Comment: @HarsH1610 Sorry, there's a lot of things going on here. Is the `/pages/activate.jsp` under `WEB-INF`? Take a look at our wiki for more info and try to reword your question.

Comment: Is your context set as DAMS in weblogic.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been a comment, but my reputation doesn't allow me to do so.Declare the `index.jsp` as *welcome-file-list* in web.xml.

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```